# Errors when I test my DLL in a test client project

Tags: c++, dll, header, dllimport

I created dll project and compile it. Then I created test client project and try to use DLL as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019
Some error occures when I include header file into test client project:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"   CppLibTest  D:\robocad\robocadSimLibCpp\robocadSimLibCpp\RE21mini.h 10  
Error (active)  E0725   name must be a namespace name   CppLibTest  D:\robocad\robocadSimLibCpp\robocadSimLibCpp\RE21mini.h 16  
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp': No such file or directory  CppLibTest  D:\robocad\robocadSimLibCpp\robocadSimLibCpp\RE21mini.h 10
```

(You can see the composition of header and cpp files here: [DLL project doesn't build in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64465703/dll-project-doesnt-build-in-visual-studio-2019/64474236?noredirect=1#comment114011784_64474236))

Some info: I built DLL project on x64 and release modes and run test client project on the same modes
What should I do to avoid the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you havn't add path of opencv2 to your client project's IncludePath.If you do not want to do this ,you should avoid to include opencv2 files in header files that your client project include.